# Delay img.src load with timeout before throwing .onerror

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, src, onerror

I am using this code to detect if a user is logged into pinterest:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "https://www.pinterest.com/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Ffavicon.ico";
img.onload = function() {
    console.log('Visitor is logged in to Pinterest ');
};
img.onerror = function() {
    console.error('Visitor is not logged in to Pinterest ');
};
</script>
```

It's based on [this script](http://webkay.robinlinus.com/scripts/social-media.js) and [here is explained](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11415462) how it works.

The problem is that it doesn't work. It shows me as not logged in, even if I am. Thats because there is a slight 2 second delay before it redirects me to the favicon.

So as the image doesn't loads immediately, it throws an error with the img.onerror function. How can I build in a timeout or slight delay before the error or success is thrown?

Comment: hitting the img.src in browser does not return the image.Can you please check the url.I created this https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/vy9ppwe7/ & it seems to work fine

Comment: @user2181397 are you logged into pinterest when trying to hit the img.src in the browser? If you are not logged in, the image will not load. The image loads only after a 2 second delay if you are already logged in. The script works fine as you showed in your jsfiddle. But only if the image loads immediately. It stops working if there is a slight delay, thats why I am asking for a timeout or something similar